# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object when trying to upload file usnig exprerss-fileupload

Tags: node.js, file-upload

Im really new here and im learning. I cant figure out the problem going inside my code. Im trying to upload a file and move it yo my desired directory by express file upload .But it always showing this error. Here is my app.js code

```js
//DECLARATION
var express    = require('express');
var login    = require('./controllers/login');
var signup    = require('./controllers/signup');
var home    = require('./controllers/home');
var logout    = require('./controllers/logout');
var admin    = require('./controllers/admin');
var member    = require('./controllers/member');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var exSession   = require('express-session');
var cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
var busboy = require('then-busboy');
var path = require('path');
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
var app    = express();




//CONFIGURATION
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


//MIDDLEWARES
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(fileUpload());


app.use('/home', home);
app.use('/admin', admin);
app.use('/member', member);
app.use('/logout', logout);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/signup', signup);
app.use('/assets', express.static('ext'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'ext')));

//ROUTES
app.get('/', (req, res)=> res.render('home/index'));

//SERVER STARTUP
app.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('server started at 3000...');
});
```

here is my router code: Home.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var userModel = require.main.require('./model/user-model');

var router = express.Router();

router.post("/signup", function(req, res){
var name=req.body.name;
var uname=req.body.uname;
var email=req.body.email;
var mobile=req.body.mobile;
var password=req.body.password;
var type="member";

  if (Object.keys(req.file).length == 0) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  }

  // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
  var sampleFile = req.file.uploaded_image;

  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
  sampleFile.mv('/assets/images/users'+sampleFile+"."+file.mimetype, function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);

    res.send('File uploaded!');
  });


if(name!=""&& uname!=""&&email!=""&&mobile!=""&&password!=""){
 var user = {
  name:name,
  uname: uname,
   email:email,
  mobile:mobile,
  password: password,
  type: type,
  image:uname,
 };

 userModel.insert(user, function(status){

  if(status){
   res.render('seller/success');
  }else{
   res.render('error');
  }
 });

}else
{
 res.render('error');
}
});

module.exports = router;
```

And the ejs form signup.ejs:

```html
<form method="post" >

     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>Name:
       </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="name"/>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Username:
       </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="uname"/>
       </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>Email:
       </td>
       <td><input type="email" name="email"/>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Mobile:
       </td>
       <td><input type="number" name="mobile"/>
       </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>Password:
       </td>
       <td><input type="password" name="password"/>
       </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>
                <input  type="file" name="uploaded_image" accept=""/>
       </td>
       <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Signup" />
       </td>
      </tr>

     </table>

     <br>
    </form>
```

Here usermodel is a custom module which actually performs several CRUD operation. Help me figuring out my problem. I tried many solutions like using multi-part, methodOverrid etc. Nothing seems working.